# DynamoDB: multiple calls to TransactWriteItems with the same ClientRequestToken for idempotency

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

reading up on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html#DDB-TransactWriteItems-request-ClientRequestToken), I'm a bit confuse about maintaining idempotent when calling TransactWriteItems with `ClientRequestToken`. Example, if I:

```cs
string requestToken = "abc123";
var result1 = await dbClient.TransactWriteItemsAsync(new TransactWriteItemsRequest
              {
                 TransactItems = list1,
                 ClientRequestToken = requestToken
              });

var result2 = await dbClient.TransactWriteItemsAsync(new TransactWriteItemsRequest
              {
                 TransactItems = list2,
                 ClientRequestToken = requestToken
              });
```

If the `result2` fails, does it also revert back the first `TransactWriteItemsAsync` in `result1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `dbClient.TransactWriteItemsAsync` is it's own transaction, consisting of a list of `TransactWriteItem`s, encapsulated in `TransactWriteItemsRequest`

So `result1` and `result2` are two different transactions. Sharing the `ClientRequestToken` is not ideal as it's used of idempotency. So if `result1` has executed, `result2` will be ignored.

`ClientRequestToken` can be used to retry

```
var result1 = await dbClient.TransactWriteItemsAsync(new TransactWriteItemsRequest
              {
                 TransactItems = list1,
                 ClientRequestToken = requestToken
              });
```

for example. If this call fails for some reason, it's safe to retry it considering you are using the same token.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I misunderstood the term `idempotency` in the first place. My initial intention was to overcome the 25 request limit per TransactWriteItem by splitting into multiple calls using `ClientRequestToken`. And if any call failed, all will be roll-back. Do you have any 'painless' solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately 25 operations is max per transaction. But that be sufficient for most cases. When I worked with DynamoDB a while back, transactions were not even supported. So if you need better acid support, better go with Sql.